# Pass complex parameter between pages

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

i'm new on Blazor Server, i'm trying to pass a class from one page to another, obviously i can't pass in the route of the page, there is something like session or viewbag in blazor server?

Now i use NavigationManager to pass from one page to another

```
          NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/loginsubscription", true);
```

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843862/c-sharp-blazor-how-to-pass-a-list-to-a-page/60846791#60846791

Comment: Incidentally, the second parameter to the NavigateTo method should be false, not true, unless you want to navigate outside the space of your SPA .

Comment: I've seen this answer, but this means that i have to create a service foreach different parameter i need to pass? Yes in this case it's because auth pages are outside the spa

Comment: No, you don't have to write a service for each object you pass (within your SPA). You should adopt the State pattern to implement such tasks. What is loginsubscription ?

Comment: Is the route of a razor page

Comment: Perhaps you try to serialize your object  into json and pass it as a query string as part of the url passed to the NavigateTo method....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# blazor how to pass a List to a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60843862/c-sharp-blazor-how-to-pass-a-list-to-a-page)

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to use static dictionary to store global data,

use Guid as key to store your class object

and pass the Guid to anther page, use it to get the object back .

---

Another way ,
Use scoped service to share data / objects

In Startup.cs

you can add your own 'Scoped' service :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ......
   services.AddScoped<MyScopeService>();
}
```

```
public class MyScopeService : Dictionary<string,object>
{
}
```

source page :

```
@inject NavigationManager nav
@inject MyScopeService mss
@code{
    void GoAnotherPage()
    {
        mss["mydata"] = new object[] { "hello", "world", 12345 };
        nav.NavigateTo("/Test_Controls",false);//do not relead
    }
}
<button @onclick="GoAnotherPage">GoAnotherPage</button>
```

target page:

```
@page "/Test_Controls"

@inject MyScopeService mss

@{
    object mydata;
    if (!mss.TryGetValue("mydata", out mydata))
    {
        <div>Oops , session expipred, please try again.</div>
        return;
    }
}

@foreach (object obj in (object[])mydata)
{
    <div> item is @obj  </div>
}
```